# Facebook connect javascript SDK issue in Edge since 28th August 2019

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, microsoft-edge, trackjs

We noticed facebook connect issue only for Edge browser:

> Failed to construct 'Request': Invalid argument.

Stack trace:

> TypeError: Failed to construct 'Request': Invalid argument.
>      at Anonymous function (https://d2zah9y47r7bi2.cloudfront.net/releases/current/tracker.js:21:358)
>      at h (https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js?hash=0f8f5b593a5516f4964c585f61d84200&ua=modern_es6:108:10805)
>      at c (https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js?hash=0f8f5b593a5516f4964c585f61d84200&ua=modern_es6:108:11202)
>      at z (https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js?hash=0f8f5b593a5516f4964c585f61d84200&ua=modern_es6:108:5265)
>      at d (https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js?hash=0f8f5b593a5516f4964c585f61d84200&ua=modern_es6:108:12427)
>      at Anonymous function (https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js?hash=0f8f5b593a5516f4964c585f61d84200&ua=modern_es6:151:1716)
>      at Anonymous function (https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js?hash=0f8f5b593a5516f4964c585f61d84200&ua=modern_es6:95:924)
>      at Array.prototype.forEach (native code)
>      at c (https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js?hash=0f8f5b593a5516f4964c585f61d84200&ua=modern_es6:45:1595)
>      at a.fire (https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js?hash=0f8f5b593a5516f4964c585f61d84200&ua=modern_es6:95:891)
>   [image]

Affected browsers:

> Edge 18.18362
>   Edge 17.17134
>   Edge 18.17763
>   Edge 16.16299
>   Edge 15.15063

Is it internal issue in SDK or issue on our side?

Comment: I'd say it's an SDK issue, since the only way the issue is on "your side" is if you changed some code on 28th August 2019 and forgot to mention it

Comment: No we didn't release any changes at least for one day before this issue.

Comment: Hi Alexandr! Todd from [TrackJS Error Monitoring](https://trackjs.com/) here. We're looking into this right now to see if we can provide more information. Can you email us at hello -at- trackjs.com?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The root cause of this error is a bug in all known versions of Microsoft Edge. Specifically, when creating a [`Request`](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#request-class) object for use in `fetch`, if the key `referrerPolicy` is provided as an init option, Edge will throw this error.

`referrerPolicy` was added to the spec about a year ago (June 2018), so it's understandable that it has not been added yet. However, they should not throw an error for an unsupported option.

The Facebook SDK is using this option in their latest version of code, which seems to have been released on or around August 27, 2019. We've seen a significant increase in this error across hundreds of internet sites since then.

I have opened bugs with both [Microsoft](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/23391036/) and [Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/2260698090722559/).

This error impact summary was sourced from [TrackJS JavaScript Error Monitoring](https://trackjs.com/) data.

### Update:

We wrote [a full summary of the Edge bug and Facebook impact here](https://trackjs.com/blog/debugging-edge-failed-to-construct-request-invalid-argument/).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will create link in our internal bug tracker.